# Is there any mathematical equation for Kirchhoff's Junction law for complicated electrical circuits?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, conservation-laws

Is there any mathematical equation for Kirchhoff's junction law? As far as I know, the junction law states :

> The total current entering the junction must be equal to the total
> current leaving the junction

I can't derive the corresponding mathematical equation.

Comment: You can not translate "current in = current out" as an equation? Do you have an example of a circuit where you can explain us what the difficulty is for you?

Answer (score 3):

If the junction consists of $n$ wires with currents $I_1 \dots I_n$ with the convention that the current sign is positive if a current is entering the junction and negative if a current is leaving the junction then Kirchhoff's law says that

$\sum_{i=1}^n I_i = 0$

Answer (score 1):

As in gandalf61's answer, it's usually easier to just define the reference direction for all branches as going out of (or in to) the node, so you can have an equation with just one summation and 0 on the other side of the equals sign.

If you really want an equation for the "current in = current out" form of the law, then you can use

$$\sum_{i\in A} I_i = \sum_{j\in B}I_j$$

where $A$ is the set of indices of branches whose current enters the node in question and $B$ is the set of indices of branches whose current exits the node.